# How can I enable short (4 lowercase letters) standard user password in Ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: login, password

I'm trying to set up a laptop for a 4 year old so I don't need a super strong password.
I've tried to reset the min password length by editing /etc/pam.d/common-password as follows:

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
password        requisite                       pam_pwquality.so retry=3
password        [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512 minlen=4
password        sufficient                      pam_sss.so use_authtok
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
password        requisite                       pam_deny.so
```

I added minlen=4 but it doesn't work I still get prompted for a longer user password!

How can I make this work for a 4 lower case letter password?

Comment: Why not use auto login for a normal user? and keep your admin account with a password?

Comment: Thanks. Auto login worked once I rebooted after changing to auto login.

Answer (score 2):

Use passwd and type in the bad password.

You will get a warning:
BAD PASSWORD: The password is shorter than 8 characters

But just retype the bad password and "password updated successfully"

Comment: An option would be to set the user to log in automatically.

Comment: and as LarsJoo suggests, [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-autologin.html.en) is how to do it.

Comment: Thanks. Auto login solved the problem. I had seen the passswd option in terminal, but this came with all sorts of warning about being unable to access encrypted files etc so I was reluctant to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Use command:

```
$ sudo passwd YOUR_USERNAME
```

Your password will be accepted from the superuser level.